# Is it possible to export a Balsamiq mockup to Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

I am about to get underway with a project, and wanted to know if it were possible to export a design mockup to Xcode 7.3. I've done some searching on google for the answer and I've seen you can add images, but I wanted to know if you could export whole wireframe projects or if i just have to recreate it all in Xcode using the wireframe as reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible for Balsamiq to export to code. You will have to rebuild the interface in Xcode's Interface Builder, as you will be able to use Autolayout and Size Classes to create truly responsive interface for all Apple products.

References:

[`[1]` Balsamiq support "Export to Code"](https://support.balsamiq.com/desktop/exporttocode/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem, of course! If this answer helped you, please don't forget to vote up and accept as answer. :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation for the upvote to show publicly but I did :)